# Order of Precedence: Smart Pointer and Class Destructor

Tags: c++, stl, sdl

Suppose we have a class with a smart pointer. This class initializes a subsystem that the smart pointer relies on: similarly, this class closes the subsystem upon destruction.

If the smart pointer relies on said subsystem to free its memory, then if the destructor closes the subsystem first an issue arises.

```
class FontManager {
public:
    FontManager() {
        if(TTF_Init() < 0) {
            printf( "SDL_ttf could not init! SDL_ttf Error: %s\n", TTF_GetError() );
            return;
        }
    }

~FontManager() {
    TTF_Quit();
}

std::unique_ptr<TTF_Font> font;

void operator()(TTF_Font* font) const { TTF_CloseFont(font); }
};
```

If I were using raw pointers the destructor would look like this.

```
~FontManager() {
    // font is raw pointer
    TTF_CloseFont(font);
    TTF_Quit();
}
```

So, what gets called first, the pointer's destructor or the class' destructor?

Comment: [OT]: you should probably throw if you can't init your manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as subobjects are constructed at the *beginning* of a class’s constructor (in the member initializer list, perhaps implicitly), they are [destroyed at the **end**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Destruction_sequence) of the destructor (in the reverse order of their construction, as usual).

You can of course `reset` your pointers **manually** in your destructor; they will still be destroyed at the end of it, but with no effect.  But the [**real answer**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) is to encapsulate the subsystem (initialization) as its **own resource**, add an instance of that new class as an *earlier* member, and then let the containing class use the **implicit destructor**.  This has the additional benefit of guaranteeing that the subsystem is *initialized* when you use it to allocate the smart pointer’s object.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with smart pointers, but if I had initialized ```font``` to ```nullptr``` or the equivalent for smart pointers then the order of precedence would have been determined at initialization?

Comment: @FaridKaradsheh: What you do with the subobject after it’s constructed (*e.g.*, appending to a `vector`) does not affect the destruction schedule (since that would require additional storage).